# Fill cells of a new dataframe without losing some columns of the former one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a reference to a commune, a number of vote in this city and the results of a few parties.

```
    Comm    Votes   LPC     CPC     BQ
0   comm1   1315.0  2.0     424.0   572.0
1   comm2   4682.0  117.0   2053.0  1584.0
2   comm3   2397.0  2.0     40.0    192.0
3   comm4   931.0   2.0     12.0    345.0
4   comm5   842.0   47.0    209.0   76.0
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
1522    comm1523    23808.0     1588.0  4458.0  13147.0
1523    comm1524    639.0   40.0    126.0   40.0
1524    comm1525    10477.0     13.0    673.0   333.0
1525    comm1526    2674.0  1.0     55.0    194.0
1526    comm1527    1691.0  331.0   29.0    78.0
```

I have a code that creates random columns for all party columns but the original one in order to pretend to have preferences rather than votes:

```
def fill_cells(cell):
    votes_max = cell['Votes']
    all_dict = {}
    parties_temp = parties.copy()
    #iterate over parties    
    for p in parties_temp:
        preferences = ['1','2','3']
        # iterate over preferences
        for preference in preferences:
            preferences.remove(preference)
            # sample new data with equal choices
            sampled = np.random.choice(preferences, int(votes_max-cell[p])) 
            # transform into dictionary
            c_sampled = dict(collections.Counter(sampled))
            c_sampled.update({p:cell[p]})
            c_sampled['1'] = c_sampled.pop(p)
            # batch update of the dictionary keys
            all_dict.update(
                dict(zip([p+'_%s' %k for k in c_sampled.keys()],c_sampled.values()))
            )
            # but I'm loosing the city references
    return pd.Series(all_dict)
```

It returns:

```
LPC_2   LPC_3   LPC_1   CPC_2   CPC_3   CPC_1   BQ_2    BQ_3    BQ_1
0   891.0   487.0   424.0   743.0   373.0   572.0   1313.0  683.0   2.0
1   2629.0  1342.0  2053.0  3098.0  1603.0  1584.0  4565.0  2301.0  117.0
2   2357.0  1186.0  40.0    2205.0  1047.0  192.0   2395.0  1171.0  2.0
3   919.0   451.0   12.0    586.0   288.0   345.0   929.0   455.0   2.0
4   633.0   309.0   209.0   766.0   399.0   76.0    795.0   396.0   47.0
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
1520    1088.0  536.0   42.0    970.0   462.0   160.0   1117.0  540.0   13.0
1521    4742.0  2341.0  219.0   3655.0  1865.0  1306.0  4705.0  2375.0  256.0
1522    19350.0     9733.0  4458.0  10661.0     5352.0  13147.0     22220.0     11100.0     1588.0
1523    513.0   264.0   126.0   599.0   267.0   40.0    599.0   306.0   40.0
1524    9804.0  4885.0  673.0   10144.0     5012.0  333.0   10464.0     5162.0  13.0
```

However with this code I lose the votes and the city reference. How can I keep them?

I tried:

```
def fill_cells(cell):
    votes_max = cell['Votes']
    all_dict = {}
    parties_temp = parties.copy()
    #iterate over parties    
    for p in parties_temp:
        # preferences = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11']
        preferences = ['1','2','3']
        # iterate over preferences
        for preference in preferences:
            preferences.remove(preference)
            # sample new data with equal choices
            sampled = np.random.choice(preferences, int(votes_max-cell[p])) 
            # transform into dictionary
            c_sampled = dict(collections.Counter(sampled))
            c_sampled.update({p:cell[p]})
            c_sampled['1'] = c_sampled.pop(p)
            # batch update of the dictionary keys
            all_dict.update(
                dict(zip(cell['Votes'],cell['Comm'],[p+'_%s' %k for k in c_sampled.keys()],c_sampled.values()))
            )
    return pd.Series(all_dict)
```

But it returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-255-dd1231fd4f2d> in <module>
----> 1 df_test.apply(fill_cells, axis =1)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6926             kwds=kwds,
   6927         )
-> 6928         return op.get_result()
   6929 
   6930     def applymap(self, func):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    184             return self.apply_raw()
    185 
--> 186         return self.apply_standard()
    187 
    188     def apply_empty_result(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    290 
    291         # compute the result using the series generator
--> 292         self.apply_series_generator()
    293 
    294         # wrap results

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    319             try:
    320                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 321                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    322                     keys.append(v.name)
    323             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-253-d0d8d6a4b22d> in fill_cells(cell)
     18             # batch update of the dictionary keys
     19             all_dict.update(
---> 20                 dict(zip(cell['Votes'],cell['Comm'],[p+'_%s' %k for k in c_sampled.keys()],c_sampled.values()))
     21             )
     22     return pd.Series(all_dict)

TypeError: ('zip argument #1 must support iteration', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: The column votes will always be the sum of votes for each party for that particular commune or are they the expected votes in that commune (voting population)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a major doubt about empty values in the dataframe. 
I suppose we are talking about this kind of dataframe, where all parties and all communes are listed, 
but with NULL values here and there. Consider my example:

```
    print(df)
        Comm   Votes    LPC     CPC      BQ
    0  comm1  1315.0    2.0   424.0   572.0
    1  comm2  4682.0  117.0  2053.0  1584.0
    2  comm3  2397.0    2.0    40.0   192.0
    3  comm4   931.0    2.0    12.0   345.0
    4  comm5   842.0   47.0   209.0    76.0
    5  comm6  1000.0    NaN   309.0     NaN
    6  comm7  1203.0  315.0     NaN   210.0
    7  comm8   581      NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Then comes my other doubt about situations like the one in row comm6 of my example.
Votes will be the sum of votes for the parties or will be the number of voting people for the commune?
I guess it must be the last one, because your code seems to calculate some kind of distributing for the votes among those, 
based on a random choice.

This is my solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from random import randint # integers generation
import collections  

empties = np.where(pd.isnull(df)) #map the nulls

print(empties)
(array([5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7], dtype=int32), array([2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32))
#1st array is row, 2nd is columns

rows=collections.Counter(empties[0])
#Counter({7: 3, 5: 2, 6: 1}), key is row, value will be divisor

distribution = {} # empty dictionary

for k,v in rows.items():    

    all_votes    = df.iloc[k,1:2]            # getting num of voting people for the row
    voted        = df.iloc[k,2:].sum(axis=0) # sum of votes in the row
    available    = all_votes - voted
    l_dist       = []

    #is 0 votes fair? I think so, unless is the only missing value
    if v == 1:
        l_dist = list(available)
    else:
        for i in range(v):

            if i != (v-1): #not the last one        
                l_dist.append(float(randint(0,(available.any()-sum(l_dist)))))
            else:
                l_dist.append(available.any()-sum(l_dist))

    distribution[k] = l_dist
    #example({5: [415.0, 276.0], 6: [678.0], 7: [58.0, 319.0, 204.0]})

for k,v in distribution.items():

    e        = np.array(empties)
    idx      = np.where(e[0] == k)
    row_name = 'comm'+str(k+1)
    cols_pos = np.take(e[1],idx)[0]         

    for v_pos,ind in zip(v,range(len(v))):
        col_name = df.columns[cols_pos[ind]]
        df.loc[df['Comm'] == row_name, col_name] = v[ind]

print(df)

    Comm   Votes    LPC     CPC      BQ
0  comm1  1315.0    2.0   424.0   572.0
1  comm2  4682.0  117.0  2053.0  1584.0
2  comm3  2397.0    2.0    40.0   192.0
3  comm4   931.0    2.0    12.0   345.0
4  comm5   842.0   47.0   209.0    76.0
5  comm6  1000.0  415.0   309.0   276.0
6  comm7  1203.0  315.0   678.0   210.0
7  comm8   581.0   58.0   319.0   204.0
```